# Object in RinSim that can move through other objects

Tags: rinsim

We're trying to find or develop an object in RinSim with the following properties:

- It can traverse the road model
- It can move through other objects that are physically present on the
  road model
- It can move against the direction of the road model

  So, it should not really be physically on the road model, but is more like an abstract thing. Does anyone know anything in RinSim we can use?
  Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason to add objects in a `RoadModel` is because they are part of a physical reality that imposes certain constraints on these objects' behavior. The object you describe doesn't seem to be part of this physical reality, therefore, adding it in a `RoadModel` is probably not a good idea.

If you are just interested in traversing the graph (in case of a `GraphRoadModel`), you can access the graph directly via `GraphRoadModel.getGraph()`.