# How to track the path a message has followed through the PDPModel?

Tags: rinsim

We are implementing a delegate-MAS solution where intention, feasibility and exploration ants are depicted by Messages in a CommsModel (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50386342/9804619)). We would like to track the path these messages have followed through the model, by adding their location to a Queue every tick. We cannot find a way to retrieve their position however. Is there a method for this we can use? Do we need to add messages as roadusers to the roadmodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are implementing the ants as `MessageContents` using a `CommModel` then these 'ants' do not have a position and are not added to a model. They are just regular Java objects. In this case, you'll have to implement any position tracking yourself.

If you are implementing the ants as a `CommUser` then they are message senders and may have a position. Keeping track of the position can then be implemented by requesting the position at every tick.